# Order the result of a join

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables:

```
Deal has many Opportunities
Opportunity belongs to Deal
```

I'm trying to order a join query that displays a list of opportunities based on their status and also the status of the deal. The query works fine except when I add `.order("deal.addr_street desc")` at the end.

```
@opportunities = Opportunity.joins(:opportunity_status).where("opportunity_statuses.id in (1, 2, 3, 6)").joins(:deal).merge(Deal.joins(:deal_status).where("deal_statuses.deal_status in ('On Market', 'Pre-sale')")).order("deal.addr_street desc")
```

The error is:

> *SQLException: no such column: opportunity.deal.addr_street: SELECT "opportunities".* FROM "opportunities" INNER JOIN
>   "opportunity_statuses" ON "opportunity_statuses"."id" =
>   "opportunities"."opportunity_status_id" INNER JOIN "deals" ON
>   "deals"."id" = "opportunities"."deal_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN
>   "deal_statuses" ON "deal_statuses"."id" = "deals"."deal_status_id"
>   WHERE (opportunity_statuses.id in (1, 2, 3, 6)) AND
>   (deal_statuses.deal_status in ('On Market', 'Pre-sale'))  ORDER BY
>   opportunity.deal.addr_street desc*

Is anyone able to tell me how can I order the result of the join? I'm on rails4

Nick

Comment: I think it's just the matter of pluralizing your `deal` table name in the `order` call as: `order("deals.addr_street desc")`.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. If you do a proper reply I'll set it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pluralize your table name in the order clause

```
(...).order("deals.addr_street desc")
```